# ¿Por qué no se asignan los valores en los atributos? Java

Tags: java, poo

Estoy intentando hacer una suma sencilla de dos fracciones usando objetos en Java, pero por alguna razón me sale el resultado por defecto del constructor, es decir, `0/1`. Creo que el error ha de estar que en el constructor no asigno bien los valores a los atributos, pero no soy capaz de ver donde se encuentra el error.

Resultado del depurador:

> La suma, utilizando el metodo de clase, entre 0/1 + 0/1 es 0/1

Código de la clase:

```
public class Fraccion {

/***************************
 * 
 *  Declaración de atributos
 *
 * *************************    
 */

private int numerador, denominador;
private static int numFracciones = 0;

/*
 *  Constructor nativo: creador de fraccion "0/1"
 */

public Fraccion() {

    this.numerador = 0;
    this.denominador = 1;
    numFracciones++;
}

/*
 *  Constructor asginador : asigna valores a los atributos de tipo CLASE.
 */

public Fraccion(int numerador, int denominador) {

    this.numerador = numerador;
    this.denominador = denominador;
    numFracciones++;
    
    
}

/*
 *  Constructor asignador :  asigna valores a los atributos de tipo OBJETO.
 */

public Fraccion(Fraccion Fraccion) {
    
    this(Fraccion.getNumerador(), Fraccion.getDenominador());
    
}
public static Fraccion sumar(Fraccion a, Fraccion b) {
    

    

    if(a.denominador == b.denominador)
    {
        a.numerador = a.numerador + b.numerador;
        a.denominador = a.denominador;
    
    } 
    
    return a;
    
    
}
```

Código donde se usa la clase:

```
public class TestFraccion {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    Fraccion frac1 = new Fraccion(1, 5);
    
    Fraccion frac2 = new Fraccion(4, 5);
    
    Fraccion frac3 = new Fraccion(-11, 22);
    
    Fraccion frac4 = new Fraccion(frac2);
    
    /*
     *  Inicio de pruebas
     * 
     */
    
    System.out.println("La suma, utilizando el método de clase, entre " + frac1 + " + " + frac2 + " es " + Fraccion.sumar(frac1, frac2));
    
    
}


}
```

Comment: Comparto este video donde Carlos Obregon nos explica como implementar objetos y buenas practica y donde usa el ejemplo de fracciones para hacerlo, espero le ayude https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=43rVrnwbBKo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faltan algunos elementos en el código de para identificar donde está el detalle en específico, sin embargo la siguiente clase funciona con la respuesta que estás buscando.

```
public class Fraccion {

    /***************************
     * 
     *  Declaración de atributos
     *
     * *************************    
     */

    private int numerador, denominador;
    private static int numFracciones = 0;

    /*
     *  Constructor nativo: creador de fraccion "0/1"
     */

    public Fraccion() {

        this.numerador = 0;
        this.denominador = 1;
        numFracciones++;
    }

    /*
     *  Constructor asginador : asigna valores a los atributos de tipo CLASE.
     */

    public Fraccion(int numerador, int denominador) {

        this.numerador = numerador;
        this.denominador = denominador;
        numFracciones++;
        
        
    }

    /*
     *  Constructor asignador :  asigna valores a los atributos de tipo OBJETO.
     */

    public Fraccion(Fraccion Fraccion) {
        
        this(Fraccion.getNumerador(), Fraccion.getDenominador());
        
    }

    private int getNumerador(){
        return this.numerador;
    }

    private int getDenominador(){
        return this.denominador;
    }

    public static Fraccion sumar(Fraccion a, Fraccion b) {
        Fraccion r = new Fraccion();

        if(a.denominador == b.denominador)
        {
            r.numerador = a.numerador + b.numerador;
            r.denominador = a.denominador;
        
        } 
        
        return r;    
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.numerador + "/" + this.denominador;
    }

}
```

En donde se integra la sobre escritura del método toString para preparar la respuesta de la salida de la consola, donde asumo que pueda estar el detalle.

También hay que corregir el método sumar ya que en tu código haces un cambio de parámetros a tu objeto frac1 y la respuesta daba como salida el retorno de frac1, tanto al inicio como al final, cuando en realidad lo que se espera (asumiendo el mensaje de la salida) es un nuevo objeto resultante, por eso en este método de sumar crea un nuevo objeto "r" como respuesta.

Comment: ¿Puedes comentar donde estaba el detalle?, para tener referencia de la solución